# Dynamic change of mouse sensivity in Counter-Strike GO on linux

Tags: linux, mouse, linux-device-driver, x11, xinput

I tried to implement mouse sensivity toggling by some button in Counter-Strike GO on linux so that sensitivity will change when the button is pressed and sensivity will return to the normal when the button is released.

I tried to do that with xinput utility and "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" property. It is worked in CS:GO menu, but has no affect in the game. I haven't found anything about other ways to change mouse sensivity from command line and haven't found anything about usbhid mouse driver configuration from command line.

Actually, I am planning to try to modify linux mouse driver. But before I started to modify the driver I decided to ask does anybody know how to change mouse sensivity from the from command line so that it will affect the mouse sensivity in CS:GO.

Comment: This is because CS:GO intentionally disallows keyboard macros like this. I believe it's technically counted as hacking, according to their EULA. Even if it's not, it isn't possible, and might well get you banned if you find a workaround that does function.

Comment: I don't believe it is a hack because I am not going to modify CS:GO program or get any data from CS:GO. Every gamer mouse now could change sensitivity by some button and most of them could configure macroses by the mouse driver (in Windows, at least). Do you think that every player with gamer mouse should be banned for hacking?

Comment: It's not what I think, it's what Valve does. Personally, I think it's stupid, but their software treats all side-scripts as illegal. The other players can use their buttons because those are built into the mouse and hardware-based, not software-based, so Valve can't check for them. Personally, I think Valve is stupid, but they make the rules.